# Find Results with at Least One term from array

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm writing a search algorithm. For the last portion of it, I want to split their search into individual words and then find any results that have at least one of those words in it. Is there any function that would work something like "ContainsAny" below? Otherwise, how can I make that happen?

```
string[] splitStr = text.Split();
result = db.Table.Where(x => x.Name.ContainsAny(splitStr).FirstOrDefault();
```

For example, if they search for "Metal Spoon" both "Metal Chair" and "spoon book" would be valid results because each contains at least one of the search terms.

Comment: regex or intersect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `ContainsAny`, but you can use combination of [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) and  [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
var results = db.Table.Where(x => splitStr.Any(s => x.Name.Contains(s)));
```